# Django Polls App: AttributeError: 'Choice' object has no attribute 'question_text'

Tags: python, django

I was doing the tutorial on the Django website, when I got this error.
I am using OS X 10.10.

```
>>> q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 458, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "/Users/anushrutgupta/Documents/IMG/Django/mysite/polls/models.py", line 22, in __str__
    return self.choice_text
AttributeError: 'Choice' object has no attribute 'question_text'
>>>
```

My models.py:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() -datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):   
        return self.choice_text
```

Is something wrong in the models?

Comment: Please show your model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a typo in your code on line 22 of `models.py`, you have `return self.question_text` but it should be `return self.choice_text`.

**EDIT**: I see you are using Python 2.7, with Python 2 you need to use `__unicode__` and not `__str__`.

> `__str__` or `__unicode__`?
>
> On Python 3, it’s easy, just use `__str__()`.
>
> On Python 2, you should define `__unicode__()` methods returning unicode values instead. Django models have a default `__str__()` method that calls `__unicode__()` and converts the result to a UTF-8 bytestring. This means that `unicode(p)` will return a Unicode string, and `str(p)` will return a bytestring, with characters encoded as UTF-8. Python does the opposite: object has a `__unicode__` method that calls `__str__` and interprets the result as an ASCII bytestring. This difference can create confusion.
>
> If all of this is gibberish to you, just use Python 3.

Comment: Okay I changed it. Now the new error has choice instead of question. Error remains the same. See above.
Thanks by the way.

Comment: Did you edit the error message? Because it is saying `line 22, in __str__ return self.choice_text` and then `AttributeError: 'Choice' object has no attribute 'question_text'` which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

So while defining `q`, please use `.get()` if you weren't already. 
You can read on the difference between `.filter()` and `.get()` in official documentation. 
As far as I can recall, `.filter()` doesn't hold the object for you to manipulate it using its attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem, I was also committing the same mistake
when you are defining the variable q,

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1) #it should be like this
q.choice_set.all() #this will show an empty list (only if it's empty)
q.choice_set.create(choice_text="sheela ki jawani", votes=0) #and so on
```

I was doing the first step of defining q wrongly instead of .get (pk=1), I was using

```
q = Question.objects.all() #this is wrong
```

Comment: I liked "sheela ki jawani"

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same exercise and based on your code I managed to make mine work. (show Question: What's up?). I must say I find the step-by-step instructions in the tutorial pretty confusing.

My code has two extra lines:

```
 from __future__ import unicode_literals # future between underscores, 2 on each side
```

and

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the two tables are linked together using the foreign key "question"

For the table "Question" to relate to the table "Choices", you need to add a parameter called "related_name" in the ForeignKeyField

Like that, for the questions to be mapped with 1 or n choices, you can use the related name

The code would look like this:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="choice_set")
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```